# Pre-populate an Account name on my vf page for creating contacts

Tags: apex, visualforce, account, contact

My visualforce page creates many contacts in one go. I want to pre-populate a certain account name when the page is loaded. Even though it always pre-populates a certain account, user should have the ability to use the lookup and change to another account if wanted. How can I do this?

My visualforce code used in the pageblocktable

```
<apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
    <apex:inputField value="{!eachRecord.record.AccountId}" required="true"/>
</apex:column>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class AddMultipleContactsController {

    public List<WrapperContactList> contList {get; set;}
    public Integer rowToRemove {get; set;}

    public AddMultipleContactsController() {
        contList = new List<WrapperContactList>();
        addNewRowToContList();
    }

    public void addNewRowToContList(){
        contList = AddMultipleContactsHelper.addNewRowToContList(contList);
    }

    public void removeRowFromContList(){
        contList = AddMultipleContactsHelper.removeRowToContList(rowToRemove, contList);
    }

    public PageReference SaveMultipleContacts(){
        try{
            AddMultipleContactsHelper.save(contList);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));
        }
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'All Contact Records have been successfully Saved'));
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference SaveMultipleContactsAndClose(){
        try{
        AddMultipleContactsHelper.save(contList);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));
        }
        PageReference contactPage = new PageReference('/003/o');
        return contactPage;
    }

    public class WrapperContactList{
        public Integer index {get; set;}
        public Contact record {
        get{
            if(record.AccountId == null){
                Account_Setting__c m = new Account_Setting__c.getInstance();
                record.AccountId = m.Acccount_Id__c;
            }
            return record;
        } set {record = value;}
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible using a custom setting ? Add the Id of the wanted Account to the Custom setting and retrieving from the controller ?

Comment: yes you can do in that way and inside your controller you can fetch the value from custom setting and assign that to contact.Accountid field

Comment: @Himanshu can you please provide me an example to follow ? I'm a bit confused to get this done

Comment: do you already have controller of this vf page ?

Comment: @Himanshu yes I updated my question with the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hierarchy custom setting into your system by following these steps

[image: Create Hierarachy custom setting]

Define new custom field of type text.

[image]

Click on Manage to fill Account id value.

[image]

After creating custom settings you can access that value inside your controller in following way.

```
 public contact record {
  get {
     //fill only if accountid is null but you can put some other logic here. 
     if(record.Accountid==null)
     {
        //Call custom setting and fill the account id.
        Manage_System__c m = Manage_System__c.getinstance();

        record.Accountid = m.Account_ID__c;
     }
     return record; 
  }
  set { record = value; }


}
```

Comment: This is very Helpful ! I'm currently trying this solution, this code logic should be added to my parameter in my Wrapper class right ?

Comment: yes. that is correct. the basic idea is reading the value from custom setting and assign that to contact AccountId field

Comment: I'm currently having problems accessing the getInstance() method. I'm getting the error "Invalid type: Account_Setting__c.getInstance". I have updated my question with what I tried. Help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: it is only Account_Setting__c m = Account_Setting__c.getinstance(); there is no new keyword between them.

Comment: Yes That saved ! your guidance is much appreciated! Everything works perfectly ! My controller works very well !!!

Comment: perfect! kudos to your effort :)

Comment: Kudos for you too !!! :)